# How get file source control statistics in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I would like to be able to get the list of the most often updated files in a team project (the files with the most associated changesets).

Is there any way to do this without having to use the SDK and write a custom tool ?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed TFS 2012 report services you might be able to get this info from the reports server or straight from the stats database. If you have it installed, you can access it through browser:

```
http://TFSSERVER:80/Reports
```